# Animate background with Loop in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, view, background

Using this code on my view to make animated background.

Actually have 3 pictures named `background_screen-1.png`, `background_screen-2.png`, `background_screen-3.png`

In my `viewDidLoad` I use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"background_screen-" duration:1.0f]];   
}
```

Only the `background_screen-1.png` is displaying. How can I get a loop between my 3 pictures to have an animation background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an `UIImageView` and you can do like below, as `UIImageView` has inbuilt method to animate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load images
    NSArray *imageNames = @[@"win_1.png", @"win_2.png", @"win_3.png", @"win_4.png",
                        @"win_5.png", @"win_6.png", @"win_7.png", @"win_8.png",
                        @"win_9.png", @"win_10.png", @"win_11.png", @"win_12.png",
                        @"win_13.png", @"win_14.png", @"win_15.png", @"win_16.png"];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    // Normal Animation
    UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
    animationImageView.animationImages = images;
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`colorWithPatternImage` creates a static color, not a color that changes in time.

You could use an `UIImageView` as the background of your ViewController. And just use your animated image as the `image` of that `UIImageView`.